# When can one find holomorphic sections vanishing at a point to a certain order?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, singularity-theory, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold (say of dimension $2$) and $L \rightarrow X $ a holomorphic line bundle. Consider the following statements:

Statement $A_0$: Given any point $p\in X$, there exists a homolorphic section $f_{00} \in H^0(X,L)$, such that $f_{00}(p) \neq 0$.

Statement $A_1$: Given any point $p\in X$, there exists two 
homolorphic sections $f_{10}, ~~f_{01} \in H^0(X,L)$, such that 
$$ f_{10}(p), ~~~f_{10}(p) =0 $$ 
and $\nabla f_{10}\big{|}_p$ and $\nabla f_{01}\big{|}_p$ 
are linearly independent in $TX_p^* \otimes L_p$.

$\textbf{Question:}$ Give a sufficient criteria on the line bundle 
$L \rightarrow X $ to guarantee that statement $A_0$ and $A_1$ are true. 
For example, does being "sufficiently ample" guarantee this?

$\textbf{Edit:} $ Statement $A_1$ was incorrectly stated before. I have also 
removed the remaining statements, since they were not what I wanted.

Comment: It looks like you want a very ample bundle, though I do not quite understand the meaning of $A_2$ and, hence, the further extension.

Comment: @Alex: You are right, $A_2$ was incorrectly stated. I believe my statement is now correct. Said in words, I am saying that given a point $p$, there should exist a section $f$ that has a genuine $A_1$-node at $p$ (the singularity looks like x^2+y^2 =0 in local coordinates).

Comment: @Alex: Why does "very ample" guarantee statements $A_0$ and $A_1$?

Comment: By the definition of very ample?

Comment: I think $A_1$ could be restated as well, but, essentially, $A_0+A_1=\text{very ample}$.

Comment: @Alex: I am sorry, I had written statement $A_1$ incorrectly. I have written the exact condition I want now. Does "very ample" guarantee this?

Comment: Yes, it does. You can see it yourself by working with hyperplane sections in embedded $X$ instead of sections of line bundle.

Comment: It seems to me this is a bit weaker than very ample, no? In particular, theres no reason for this line bundle to separate points.. It could just be something like X=YxZ, and the line bundle is the trivial bundle on Y twisted by something very ample on Z...